# How to put email body and attachment in one JSON Object using imap NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, imap, attachment

I like to store my email body like [the date, subject, to, from, attachment] in a JSON object, but I cannot find a solution that allows me to get my attachment without using `msg.once('attributes',...)`.

I don't need to download the attachment. I just need put the encoded BASE64 attachment inside my JSON Object.

**My Code:**

```
var mail = {
  date: "",
  Subject: "",
  Sender: "",
  Receiver: "",
  Attachment: null
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
      imap.openBox('INBOX', true, function(err, box) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
          bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'],
          struct: true
        });
        f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
          simpleParser(stream).then(parsed => {
            var mail = {
              date: parsed.date,
              Subject: parsed.subject,
              Sender: parsed.from.value,
              Receiver: parsed.to.value,
              Attachment: null //i don't know how to get the attachment
              it always says attachment = [] when i console log parsed

            }
          })
        });
        msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
            var attachments = findAttachmentParts(attrs.struct);
            console.log(prefix + 'Has attachments: %d', attachments.length);
            for (var i = 0, len = attachments.length; i < len; ++i) {
              var attachment = attachments[i];
            },
            language: null
          }
          */
          console.log(prefix + 'Fetching attachment %s', attachment.params.name);
          var f = imap.fetch(attrs.uid, { //do not use imap.seq.fetch here
            bodies: [attachment.partID],
            struct: true
          });
          //build function to process attachment message
          f.on('message', buildAttMessageFunction(attachment));
        }
      });
```

Comment: Please may you remove the parts of the code not relevant to the question? Make sure the code is a [mcve].

Comment: im sorry okay i already reduce any unecessary code

Comment: No need to apologise. I just asked so that myself and others are not overwhelmed by the amount of code.

Comment: also in my problem i want to pass that json object back to frontend in order for them to display the content of the email

Answer (score 0):

I solved this through the use of promises and simpleparser:

```
imap.search([['X-GM-RAW', 'has:attachment in:unread'], ['SINCE', new Date()], ], (err, results) = >{
    const f = imap.fetch(results, {
        bodies: ''
    });
    f.on('message', (msg) = >{
        const attributesPromise = new Promise((resolve) = >{
            msg.on('attributes', (attrs) = >{
                resolve(attrs);
            });
        });
        const bodyPromise = new Promise((resolve) = >{
            msg.on('body', async(stream) = >{
                const parsed = await simpleParser(stream);
                resolve(parsed);
            });
        });
        Promise.all([attributesPromise, bodyPromise]).then((data) = >{
            const[attributes, emailContent] = data;
            console.log(attributes, emailContent);
        });
    });
    f.once('error', (ex) = >{
        return Promise.reject(ex);
    });
    f.once('end', () = >{
        console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
        imap.end();
    });
});
```

edit: I just saw that you just needed body and attachment in one request. That is already beeing done in the `parsed` variable in below answer. However, the below answer gives you the attributes and the emailContent in once. This can be used to further update the email based on content. For example setting a label by the uid if the subject of the email contains something.